# Adding swagger to existing aws lambda (API Gateway)

Tags: aws-lambda, swagger, aws-api-gateway

Does anyone know of a link to a useful documentation on how to add swagger documentation to an existing aws lambda (API Gateway)? Some sort of a noob tutorial as I am totally new to swagger.

I have found some links, such as the following, which were not so useful or not specific to lambda:
https://blog.cloudboost.io/adding-swagger-to-existing-node-js-project-92a6624b855b
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node

Comment: I don't think you use Swagger with Lambda, rather with API Gateway. Are you using API Gateway to serve http requests to your Lambda?
If so maybe have a look here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-export-api.html#api-gateway-export-api-download-swagger-yaml-with-apig

Comment: yes, i am. but this link is quiet high level to me. is there any detailed documentation somewhere as to how i can achieve this?

Comment: Do you use `serverless` framework?

Comment: yes, i am using serverless

Answer (score 4):

I have only used Swagger with API Gateway with the old v0.5 version of `serverless` framework as there was a plugin that supported this easily. 
However, when `serverless` matured into v1.0 and up, at that time, there were no good plugins for Swagger integration.

Here are links you can check:

[Serverless Github Issue: Swagger Integration](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/1847)

[Reckon-Limited/serverless_swagger](https://github.com/Reckon-Limited/serverless_swagger)

[doapp-ryanp/serverless-plugin-swag](https://github.com/doapp-ryanp/serverless-plugin-swag)

I don't personally use the above though as my big serverless projects are now using GraphQL (where API documentation is part of the standard tooling :-) instead of REST.

Answer (score 0):

In my backend team we do the documentation using a tool that smart bear makes available, the [swagger inspector](https://inspector.swagger.io/builder) and through it we finish adjusting the doc with the [swagger hub](https://app.swaggerhub.com/).

Swagger inspector **makes a request on your endpoint and basically extracts the necessary documentation,** but some things you need to adjust, it is not the best solution, but it helps ...